# Executar uma tarefa em determinado momento

Tags: php, laravel

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de prazos e alertas. O usuário vai cadastrar um prazo, data e hora do prazo e definir se ele quer receber o alerta com 1, 2 ou 3 horas de antecedência.

Como eu poderia realizar uma função que fique checando e já está na hora de mandar o e-mail para o usuário?
Não queria fazer um CRON para rodar a cada minuto e checar se já está na hora de enviar o e-mail.

Existe alguma forma de criar um CRON automático para que ele execute somente na hora de enviar o e-mail para o usuário.

Comment: Executar somente na hora envolve verificar se já está na hora ou não (não dá para fugir disso, seja ou não cron)... Um cron seria a melhor solução neste caso, não faz mal se for minuto a minuto. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling

Comment: De qualquer forma você deverá verificar de tempo em tempo. Senão como saberá que já está na hora ? Use cron

Comment: Deixar um Schedule rodando a cada minuto e verificar na base de dados para ver se já está na hora de enviar um email, não pesaria o servidor?

Comment: Você pode utilizar o commando [`at` (Linux)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_(command)) para que o script seja executado em um determinado momento. Se não me engano, você pode executar o commando usando shell_exec e ele executará apenas uma vez no momento indicado. Entretanto, eu nunca utilizei ele via PHP, apenas via CLI.

Comment: @GabrielHeming esse comando e como esse próprio link indica, isso é similar a cron... E sem dúvida que vai ter verificar de tempo em tempo se chegou a hora de correr o programa. E está também obsoleto como diz nesse link.

Comment: @Miguel acho que lemos coisas diferentes, pesquisei [aqui](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uat.htm), [aqui](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-schedule-tasks-using-at-command-on-linux) e [aqui](https://www.lifewire.com/linux-command-at-4091646) e todas as informações que você informou agora são para windows (_[...]but is now deprecated in favor of schtasks.exe[...]_). Não localizei em nenhum lugar que está obsoleto (_Unix-Like systems_) e, mesmo que seja processado minuto/minuto, tal qual a cron, não haverá o overhead de executar o script PHP, ou seja, é menos custoso.

Comment: Sim @GabrielHeming, tens razão foi distração minha, eu vi windows e assumi que era windows. De qualquer a verificação é feita, tem de ser

Comment: Sim @Miguel, mas sem overhead, pois, o código PHP de validação (se está na hora de executar) será executado uma única vez. Ou seja, terá menos custo ao servidor. Estou longe do meu server linux para fazer um exemplo, quando eu chegar em caso eu farei (se ninguém tiver respondido ainda). Aqui há mais informações sobre `at` e suas variantes: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97882/why-do-we-need-the-at-command-in-linux

Comment: Sim, exato @GabrielHeming, o script não é sequer chamado se não for hora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que fazer o CRON rodar a cada minuto (ou no múltiplo mínimo de minutos que seu agendamento permite) não vai ser um problema, já que o job vai somente checar e só efetuar a tarefa de fato se precisar. Otimize bem essa tarefa de checar e retornar rápido caso não haja falha que está tudo em casa.

Não esqueça de verificar se você vai querer ter overlap ou não. Overlap é quando um job demora muito para executar e o próximo minuto chega disparando um próximo job em paralelo. Você pode querer isso ou não.

Lembre-se de ir sempre pelo caminho mais simples que funciona (cada projeto tem seu contexto), deixe para fazer super otimizações somente se tiver problemas de performance verificadas.

Comment: Eu utilizo Filas no laravel e vi que, após executar uma tarefa, ele deleta o registro da tabela job. Para a consulta não demorar, terei que fazer o mesmo na tabela de prazo.